# Asp.net MVC DropDownListFor list of lists from model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to show name in dropdownlist from Model that look like  `Model.list<AnotherModel>.List<string>`.

**Model**

```
public class LoginModel
{
public List<ApplicationNames> ApplicationName { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationNames
{
public string Id { get; set; }
public List<string> Applications { get; set; }//["app1","app2"]
}
```

**CSHTML**

```
@model LoginModel
        @using (Html.BeginForm("ApplicationIndex", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
        {
          @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ApplicationName,new SelectList(Model.ApplicationName,"Id","Applications"),"Select Application", new { @class = "textboxStyle", placeholder = "Select your application...", autofocus = "autofocus", autocomplete = "on", onkeypress = "btnFocusActivate(this, event)", id = "un" })
          <input type="submit" value="NEXT" class="rectangle" id="submitNext" disabled="disabled" />
        }
```

In dropdownlist instead of Applications i m getting Getting `GenericList.Object`.

what i have to modify to get `Applications` name in dropdownlist?

**Result like:**

[image: result]

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot use modal like `public string Id { get; set; } 
public List<string> Applications { get; set; }//["app1","app2"]` 
SelectList accepts a pair value `id:1,text:'my name'` 
First of all you have to fix your pairs, you are trying to push multiple `Applications` for one `Id`

Comment: Yes i have multiple applications name belong to single Id and that i want to show in dropdowlist..how to achieve that multiple `Applications` for one `id`

Comment: If that is the case, it means if user selects one `id` it will select all application names which belong to `id:1`. if what I said is correct you can make a comma separated string for application names and then show it as one record `id:1,text:'app1,app2,app3'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In dropdownlist instead of Applications i m getting Getting GenericList.Object.

> what i have to modify to get Applications name in dropdownlist?

> `public List<string> Applications { get; set; }//["app1","app2"]`

You can try to concatenate string item(s) using the specified separator, like below.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ApplicationName, new SelectList(Model.ApplicationName.Select(a=>new { Id = a.Id, Applications = String.Join(", ", a.Applications.ToArray())}), "Id", "Applications"), "Select Application", new { @class = "textboxStyle", placeholder = "Select your application...", autofocus = "autofocus", autocomplete = "on", onkeypress = "btnFocusActivate(this, event)", id = "un" })
```

Test Result

[image]

***Update:***

> it's possible to edit/append random number with id at runtime and result like each app as separate options.

To achieve above requirement, as I mentioned in comment, you can try to generate expected data based on your model data in controller action, then pass it to view to populate your dropdown, like below.

```
var Applications_list = "";


foreach (var item in model.ApplicationName)
{
    Applications_list += String.Join(",", item.Applications.ToArray()) + ",";
}

ViewBag.AppList = Applications_list.TrimEnd(',').Split(",").Select((a, index) => new { Id = index, AppName = a });
```

*Html code*

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ApplicationName, new SelectList(ViewBag.AppList, "Id", "AppName"), "Select Application", new { @class = "textboxStyle", placeholder = "Select your application...", autofocus = "autofocus", autocomplete = "on", onkeypress = "btnFocusActivate(this, event)", id = "un" })
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: it's possible to edit/append random number with id at runtime and result like each app as separate options.

Comment: Does `ApplicationName` of your model LoginModel have only one item?

Comment: no..but looking for mapping to make id unique from combination of id and text at runtime and display options in dropdown.

Comment: I suggest that you can regenerate expected `List<SelectListItem>` based on your model data from controller action and pass it to view via viewbag etc instead of writing and executing too many logic code in view.

Comment: `it's possible to edit/append random number with id at runtime and result like each app as separate options.` Hi @r08, you can did same as I shared in update to achieve the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Your class has to be plain.

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string SelectedApplicationNameItemId { get; set; }
    public List<ApplicationNameItem> ApplicationNames { get; set; }
}
public class ApplicationNameItem
{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And code for your Razor page is below. When submitted, selected value can be located in `SelectedApplicationNameItemId` property

```
Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedApplicationNameItemId, new SelectList(Model.ApplicationNames,"Id","Name"))
```